How can I find good examples of transdisciplinary literature reviews?
I'm planning on writing up a narrative literature review for publication as a journal article.  The topic is a transdisciplinary one, and so I'd like the review to cater to academic audiences across these disciplines, which poses certain challenges for how to style and structure the review, what sort of content and context to include, etc.  I'd like to see some good examples of how others have handled such reviews so that I might learn from them and perhaps adopt/adapt some of their features.
Apart from searching citation indexes like Google Scholar for terms like "transdisciplinary literature review" and browsing the results for relevant, highly cited papers, are there any other ways of finding high-quality examples?  For example, are there any books or online resources about writing literature reviews that cite some highly regarded examples?  Are there any such reviews that have won best paper awards or the like?

I suggest you go talk to the university "research" librarian. This is what they do.
